# How to set config options in wxGTK to generate libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets 3.0.5.1, and compiling from the source code. Due to other third-party dependencies, this version is preferred in my project.
With the following commands,

```
../configure --with-gtk --prefix=${INSTALLED_DIR}
make
make install
```

I can build and install the package successfully. In the ${INSTALLED_DIR}, I can find a series of .so, such as, libwx_baseu_3.0.so, libwx_gtk2u_core_3.0.so and so on.

However, I can't find the libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so. This .so was used by another codebase of my project. I want to know how to generate this libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.0.so when I compiling wxgtk?

This is a too old version of wxWidgets, can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 1):

Some headers or libraries required for building with OpenGL support must not have been found by configure, you need to check its output and, if necessary, `config.log` file that it generated to discover what exactly is missing and fix it, typically by simply installing the missing dependencies from your distribution package repositories.